# Google Cloud Endpoint + Restful + CRUD

Tags: android, google-app-engine, rest, crud

I'm using Google App Engine and Google Cloud Endpoints to communicate between my Android app (frontend) and the webservice (backend) that runs in the cloud. But I wonder about the URL's used for GET and POST.

Imagine you have a list of notes on the server each with a caption and an id. According to CRUD (create, updated, delete), the HTTP/HTTPS calls should look like that:

Get all notes:

```
GET http://domain.eu/notes
```

Get a specific note by it's id (let's say 123):

```
GET http://domain.eu/notes/id
```

and so on. But Google uses a different pattern. For instance if you use the API explorer you get calls like this:

```
GET https://domain/_ah/api/notesEndpoint/v1/notesdata
```

**Question**: Is there a general way to get a call for listing all notes? According to the annotations in the source code it should be somewhat like /notes or /notes.listNodes I simply don't understand how Google constructs the URL's

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I edited the post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Endpoints use the API-Explorer system.

**`/_ah/api`** is defined for the API Explorer, you can't change it.
**notesEndpoint** is the name of your Api, and **v1** the version you define.
**notesdata** is the name of the method. You can override the path by annotation.

Example, to access to the notes through

> domain/_ah/api/notesEndpoint/v1/notes

You have to make this method :

```
@ApiMethod(
    name = "notes.listNodes",
    path = "notes",
    httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET
 )
 public List<Foo> notesdata() {
    return myList;
 }
```

(a link to the documentation : [DOC](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations))

For information, with this system, you can explore your API with this URL :

> GET http://domain.eu/_ah/api/explorer

Comment: Perfect, using the path-argument worked. But according to the docu the relative URI path would be notes.listNodes or just listNodes unless you use the path-argument. This should enable a call like domain/_ah/api/notesEndPoint/v1/notes.listNodes but it does not work. It works only with domain/_ah/api/notesEndPoint/v1/notesdata. Using the path-argument lets you then use domain/_ah/api/notesEndPoint/v1/notes but then the API explorer does not work anymore because you'll get a 404 not found error when you click the method.

Comment: The name is used for the JS API... In your case, to access to your method in Javascript, you cann use the library **gapi** like this :
`var notes = gapi.client.notesEndPoint.notes.list();`

Comment: how about a POST example?